Ripping leaves on my hibiscus
I have an indoor/outdoor hibiscus and have kept it inside during winter months. Just repotted it and now the leaves seem to be randomly tearing. Nothing has changed other than me repotting it.

Hi Susan, it would help if you posted a photo of it.
